# jquery show/hide two divs on click and hide link

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using the following JS

```
<a href=# onClick="if($(this).next('div').css('display') == 'none') { $(this).next('div').show('fast'); } else { $(this).next('div').hide('fast'); } return false;">Add a Street Address</a>
```

and the following html

```
<div id=entry>
  <div id=label>Street</div>
  <div id=input><input name="" type="text" class="longtext" /></div></div>
<div id=entry>
  <div id=label>City/Town</div>
  <div id=input><input name="" type="text" class="longtext" /></div></div>
```

How would i modify the JS to show/hide both of those divs at once, and then make the link disappear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a. you better off using class instead of id where both share the same value (e.g. entry)

```
<div class=entry>
  <div id=label>Street</div>
  <div id=input><input name="" type="text" class="longtext" /></div></div>
<div class=entry>
  <div id=label>City/Town</div>
  <div id=input><input name="" type="text" class="longtext" /></div></div>
```

b. Hiding both divs can be done as:

```
$('.entry').hide();
```

hiding the clicked link

```
$(this).hide();
return true;
```

e.g.

```
<a id='myLinkId' href='#'>Click To Hide</a>

$('a#myLinkId').click(function(){
    $('.entry').hide();
    $(this).hide();
    return true;
});
```

Comment: The ids of label and input divs need to be unique and also returning true will fire the default anchor behaviour, which is not what you want in this situation

Answer (score 2):

First give an id to your link tag like 'link', then give you two dives two different ids, then write a js function like this :

```
show_hide = function()
{
    if(document.getElementById('link').style.display == 'none'){
         document.getElementById('link').style.display = 'inline';
         document.getElementById('entry1').style.display = 'inline';
         document.getElementById('entry2').style.display = 'inline';
    }else{
         document.getElementById('link').style.display = 'none';
         document.getElementById('entry1').style.display = 'none';                  
         document.getElementById('entry2').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: question tagged under jQuery as well, why not using hide/show methods supply by jQuery?

Comment: I don't know what jQuery is ;)

Answer (score 1):

IDs need to be unique so I have changed the ids to classes. Also, I have changed the code from being inline to being unobtrusive The jQuery would be something like the following

```
$(function() {
    $('#addressLink').click(function() {
        $('div.entry').toggle();
        $(this).hide();
        return false; // prevent the default anchor behaviour
    });    
});


<a id="addressLink" href="#">Add a Street Address</a>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="label">Street</div>
  <div class="input"><input name="" type="text" class="longtext" /></div>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="label">City/Town</div>
  <div class="input"><input name="" type="text" class="longtext" /></div>
</div>
```

Assuming that you want the `<div>` elements to be hidden initially, simply add `$('div.entry').hide();` into the document ready handler. There are other techniques that you can use here, but I would suggest hiding using JavaScript for [graceful degradation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graceful_degradation) purposes

Here's a **[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/ilewi)**. Add **/edit** to the URL to see the code

Comment: $('addressLink') should be $('#addressLink')